# What can make "pip3" to get uninstalled

Tags: pip

I was working on Flask project and I'm pretty sure I started creating in the current machine only and have build from the scratch by installed Flask under virtual environment, using "pip install Flask".

But after some days, now I tried to install "uWsgi" using pip and to my astonishment, both "pip" and "pip3" were not found. I'm sure I've not uninstalled pip and even there is no reason to do that.

So is there any way to trace when pip got uninstalled and which program did that?
Only software related thing that I've done is update Ubuntu (Not upgrade) when prompted.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked in your `apt` logs? (/var/log/apt/) to check you didn't cause it be removed because of another install/remove you did?

Answer (score 2):

`python-pip3`depends on ...

```
ca-certificates
python-pip-whl (= 18.1-5)
python3
python3-distutils
```

So removing or purging either of these will also uninstall `python-pip3`. Out of these the only obvious one would be deleting `python3`. The others are not packages you would touch yourself. But you would have a whole lot of other problems if you did remove any of these.

The log files to check for using `apt` ...

```
/var/log/apt/term.log
/var/log/apt/history.log*
```

but there is also (in case `dpkg` was used) ...

```
/var/log/dpkg.log
```

- You can use `less` or `grep` to search 2 of them. history.log uses compressed files for older logs so use `zgrep` to scan those.

With normal usage, I would believe, there is not a method that would remove package `python-pip3`.